# Setting Different onClickListener for Different Button

Tags: android

I have a activity where there are 10 identical `imageButton` all derived from the same resource `myimage.png`
I am trying to set different `onClick` listener for each of the 10 buttons using `setTag()`.
However all the `imageButton` get tied to the same listener.

Here's my code:

```
public class AllButtonsActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imageButton;
ImageButton allImageButtons[] = new ImageButton[10];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ll);

    createButtonsAndAddListener();

}

public void createButtonsAndAddListener() {
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
        imageButton.setTag(i);
        allImageButtons[i] = imageButton;
        allImageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = (Integer) imageButton.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(AllButtonsActivity.this,
                        "ImageButton"+i+ "is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        });
        parent.addView(imageButton);

    }
}
}
```

What i want is that when the i-th Button is clicked, the toast pops out a message:

> "ImageButton"+i+ "is clicked!"

Comment: Read the View.setId(int id) method's documentation. The id has to be a positive number. I don't see any other problems yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image button variable is being overwritten for each iteration of your loop. Rather than using a variable which you declare at the start of your Activity create a new one each time

```
public void createButtonsAndAddListener() {
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybutton);
        imageButton.setTag(i);
        allImageButtons[i] = imageButton;
        allImageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = (Integer) imageButton.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(AllButtonsActivity.this,
                    "ImageButton"+i+ "is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }

        });
        parent.addView(imageButton);

    }
}
```

Change your code to the code above and remove `ImageButton imageButton;` from  your activity variable declarations

Answer (score 3):

Improving the code above, I suggest you to define just one onClickListener and set it to each imageButton (a variable definition outside the method):

```
        OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener(){@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(AllButtonsActivity.this,
                    "ImageButton"+i+ "is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }

        });
```

...
And here is the method defined above (Dreagen answer):

```
public void createButtonsAndAddListener() {
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybutton);
        imageButton.setTag(i);
        allImageButtons[i] = imageButton;
        allImageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(click);
        parent.addView(imageButton);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `View` which you recieve in `onClick()` (which is actually your specific `ImageButton`), not your local `imageButton` variable.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(AllButtonsActivity.this,
                    "ImageButton"+i+ "is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is already answered but even then i want add this different approach as answer:

```
public class AllButtonsActivity extends Activity implements onClickListner{
ImageButton imageButton;
ImageButton allImageButtons[] = new ImageButton[10];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ll);
    createButtonsAndAddListener();

}

public void createButtonsAndAddListener() {
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
        imageButton.setTag(i);
        allImageButtons[i] = imageButton;
        allImageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        parent.addView(imageButton);
    }
}
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     int i = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(AllButtonsActivity.this,
                "ImageButton"+i+ "is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
}
}
```